# Как задать русский язык для CultureInfo в SpeechRecognitionEngine c# .Net

Tags: c#, .net, распознавание-речи, распознавание, мультиязычность

В строке (new SpeechRecognitionEngine(
new System.Globalization.CultureInfo( culture.ToString())) ) выпадает исключение :
-System.ArgumentException: "No recognizer of the required ID found."

```
using System;
using System.Speech.Recognition;
using System.Globalization;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CultureInfo culture = null;
            if (CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name == "ru-RU")
                culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ru-RU");
            else
                culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");

            CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;
            CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;
            // Create an in-process speech recognizer for the en-US locale.  
            using (
            SpeechRecognitionEngine recognizer =
              new SpeechRecognitionEngine(
                new System.Globalization.CultureInfo( culture.ToString())))
            {

                // Create and load a dictation grammar.  
                recognizer.LoadGrammar(new DictationGrammar());

                // Add a handler for the speech recognized event.  
                recognizer.SpeechRecognized +=
                  new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(recognizer_SpeechRecognized);

                // Configure input to the speech recognizer.  
                recognizer.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();

                // Start asynchronous, continuous speech recognition.  
                recognizer.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);

                // Keep the console window open.  
                while (true)
                {
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
        }

        // Handle the SpeechRecognized event.  
        static void recognizer_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Recognized text: " + e.Result.Text);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Документация пишет:
//       Default Culture: ru-RU
//       Default UI Culture: ru-RU

Comment: Попробуй использовать ru-ru